# AdMob cambia la actividad en app android

Tags: java, android, admob

Quisiera consultarles el porqué de mi problema. Tengo muchas actividades, 2 de ellas son: la principal y la actividad del juego. Estoy utilizando AdMob, me funciona bien en otras actividades, el problema que tengo es que cuando lo intento utilizar en un botón dentro de un Dialog, en el cual tengo un botón para "reiniciar" un juego, no me funciona. La idea es que al clickear sobre él, que muestre el anuncio; y después al cerrar el anuncio, que el juego se reinicie normalmente. Lo que está pasando es que al cerrar el anuncio, manda a la principal.

```
 //Aquí está el evento para cerrar el anuncio
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
         //Método para reiniciar el juego
            reset_game();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();

  //Este evento es para el botón de reiniciar el juego
    ImageButton resetGame =(ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.resetGame);
    resetGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                reset_game();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
   display_unlocked_card_alert();
    Log.d(  TAG,"unlocked_check value 2 = " + unlocked_check);
}
```

Sé muy bien que en reset_game no invoco ni nada de eso al Main, ya que ahí solo genero al juego, pero de todos modos lo dejo:

```
  private void reset_game(){

    HashMap data = MemoryGame.game_mode_for(mode, cards_no);
    init_table((int) data.get("rows"), (int) data.get("cols"));
    memory_game.generate((int) data.get("total_cards"));
    //init_table(4, 5);
    //memory_game.generate(4*5);
    current_turn = 0;
    select_1 = 0;
    select_2 = 0;
    c =0;

    set_timer((int) data.get("time"));
    update_game_state_view();
    update_cards_state_view();
}
```

Realmente no sé por qué sucede eso, ¿tendrá algo que ver que esté dentro de un Dialog?

**EDICIÓN**

Este problema no lo resolví, mejor cambié el modo de ver las ads.
De todos modos me gustaría saber el error o la forma de resolverlo, por simple curiosidad.

A petición, añado el código de el Dialog:

```
//Es un dialogo personalizado
private void alert_win() {

    dialog = new Dialog(GameScreen.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.winner_dialog);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


    Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bellosmcp.ttf");

    TextView moTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.moTextView);
    moTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    moTextView.setText(String.valueOf(_turn_count));
    TextView matchTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.matchTextView);
    matchTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    movesTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    matchTextView.setText(String.valueOf(_score));
    TextView pairstextView =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairstextView);
    pairstextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    pairstextView.setText(Integer.toString(c));
    ImageView closeDialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
    TextView highScoreTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.high_Score);
    highScoreTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    highScoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(user.high_score));     



//Aquí está el botón para reiniciar

ImageButton resetGame =(ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.resetGame);
    resetGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

//Aquí esta lo de las Ads

           if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
               mInterstitialAd.show();
           } else {

                reset_game();
          }               

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

La cuestión es que si mostraba las Ads, pero al momento de cerrarlo, sí reiciaba, el juego pero se cerraba la actividad redireccionando al Main del juego, ese error no lo pude resolver, mejor cambié la manera en que las ads se mostraran.

Comment: Puedes mejorar el título? Está muy genérico

Comment: que hace el metodo `requestNewInterstitial`?

Comment: Es una función de AdMob, permite abrir un nuevo anuncio

Comment: Me la modificaron, yo coloqué el título "Problema con AdMob, redirecciona al Main principal"

Comment: @xMptRTutosv acabo de ver tu pregunta, me parece que el título es incorrecto, el problema es algo común al cargar el anuncio en el Dialogo, lo cual no sucede al cargarlo en la actividad.

Comment: @xMptRTutosv podrias incluir el codigo completo del activity? especialmente los metodos que manejan el ciclo de vida del activity del juego ( oncreate, ondestroy, etc)

Comment: @x4mp73r Por favor agrega el código donde creas el dialogo y  donde agregas el anuncio.

Comment: @Elenasys Ya agregué lo que pedías, gracias.

Comment: Sin más partes del código facilitadas no se puede llegar a una conclusión clara. Ahora bien, los puntos que tendrías que revisar para encontrar la causa del fenómeno que comentas son los siguientes: - Como ya te han comentado, fíjate bien en los métodos de la Activity del juego onPause, onResume, onDestroy, onRestart y onStart en este orden. Cualquiera que hayas implementado y en el que haya un finish o un Intent. Casi seguro que la respuesta estará aquí. - ¿Controlas los ConfigChanges? Podría ser que se disparara alguno y que el código entrara en alguna parte que no tienes en cuenta. - ¿Has i

Comment: @BernatSaurí Gracias por tu atención, esa pregunta es de hace 1 año xD y no se pudo resolver, gracias de todos modos :)

Comment: @x4mp73r Acabo de ver tu comentario, nunca lo pudiste resolver? yo tuve este problema hace tiempo pero pense alguién habría respondido!!! haha ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏

Comment: @Elenasys No lo resolví , tal como dice mi _update_, cambié la forma de ver mis ads  Pero apuesto que estaba fácil, en ese tiempo tenía muchas apps en desarrollo y estaba vuelto loco  ¿Tienes una solución? o si tengo chance mas tarde lo re-analizo y quizá publique una solución

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que pasa es que cuando presionas el botón del Dialog, si el Interstitial no está cargado (cuando realizas el `if isLoaded`), te invoca el método para reiniciar el juego y descarta el Dialog (dismiss); pero si la publicidad se muestra, al momento de cerrarla, invocas directamente el método sin descartar el Dialog, por ende puede que la Activity colapse aunque lo raro es que esto debería darte un error a nivel AndroidRuntime, no sé si sea por esto que menciono pero es la única cosa rara que noto en el código.

Intenta invocando el dismiss del Dialog dentro del if del isLoaded justo después de lanzar el Interstitial con el `show()`, algo como esto:

```java
//Este evento es para el botón de reiniciar el juego
ImageButton resetGame =(ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.resetGame);
resetGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            // Cierras el Dialog para evitar que la Activity colapse...
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            reset_game();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
});
```